# What's the measure of angle ∡IEO?

Tags: geometry

For reference: In a triangle ABC, ∡B=120º.
"I" ⇒ Incenter of △ ABC.
"O"⇒ Circumcenter of △ ABC
"E" ⇒ Excenter of △ ABC relative to side BC.
Calculate the m∡IEO.

My progress:

I made the figure, marked the possible angles and drew some auxiliary lines to try to reach the solution......[image]

Comment: Additional comment: by ecenter property \measuredangle $AEG = \frac{120}{2} = 60^o$ and therefore $\measuredangle KGE = 30^o$

Comment: @MathLover..Very well highlighted...I fully agree with you...I usually try to validate the answers after I clear the doubts...see that I'm always questioning the answers in the points that I couldn't see (my doubt may be someone else's). I even changed the last validation because the trigonometric resolution, as my colleague ABC said, was for a specific case, despite being correct, it does not meet all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer to internal angles of $\triangle ABC$ as $\angle A, \angle B$ and $\angle C$

$\angle OAE = \angle 30^\circ + \angle A = \angle 30^\circ + \frac{1}{2} (60^\circ - \angle C)$

$ \angle OAE = 60^\circ - \frac{\angle C}{2} \tag1$

$\angle OCE = 30^0 + \angle ACE = 30^\circ +(90^\circ + \frac{\angle C}{2})$

$ \angle OCE= 120^\circ + \frac{\angle C}{2} \tag2$

So, $\angle OAE + \angle OCE = 180^\circ ~ $ and it follows that quadrilateral $OAEC$ is cyclic.

$ \therefore \angle IEO = \angle ACO = 30^\circ$

Comment: Where did this come from ?$\angle OCE = 30^0 + \color{blue}{(90^\circ + \frac{\angle C}{2})}$

Comment: @ACB I added some more details. Let me know if it is clear. $\angle ACE = \angle C + \frac {180^\circ - \angle C}{2}$. Also, $\angle ACO = 30^\circ$

Comment: @MathLover But ACI+ θ°=30°
θ°+IEO=30°
While these angles are non-zero, all of them are less than 30 degrees. What's your idea about?

Comment: @ACB also just as a side note, internal and external angle bisectors are always perpendicular to each other. Something we can conclude from angle chasing but good to remember.

Comment: @chemandmath $\angle ACI + \theta = 30^\circ$ is true but why $\angle IEO + \theta = 30^\circ$?

Comment: @MathLover KEO is a triangle & we have OKE + IEO + EOK = 180 degree while OKE = 90° & EOK = 60° + θ° so θ°+IEO=30°. It was one of my notes.

Comment: @chemandmath , $\angle EOK$ is not $60^\circ+\theta$. It's $\angle COK$.

Comment: @chemandmath as ACB pointed out, $\angle AOC = 120^\circ, \angle AOK = 60^\circ - \theta, \angle COK = 60^\circ + \theta$. In fact $\angle EOK = 60^\circ$

Comment: @MathLover is AE a straight line or does it make an angle at I.
Thank you

Comment: @Bometh that's a good point. Yes $A, I$ and $E$ are collinear as $I$ is the incenter and $E$ is the ex-center opposite $A$. Please read the second sentence in the link on Trillium theorem. It also talks about two small results and one of them being that $A, I$ and $E$ are collinear. https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Incenter/excenter_lemma

Comment: Excellent...could clarify some doubts:
$\angle A = \angle CAB$ ?\\
$\angle OAE = 30^o + \angle A$ ~ wouldn't ~would~ $\angle CAE$?
~Could~ clarify ~$\angle A=\frac{1}{2}(60^∘−∠C)$

Comment: @petaarantes $\angle OAE = \angle OAC + \angle CAE$. $\angle CAB = 60^\circ - \angle C$ so  $\angle CAE = \frac{1}{2} \angle CAB = \frac{1}{2} (\angle 60^\circ - \angle C)$. Also, $\angle OAC = 30^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider the fact that the bisector of $\angle ABC$ passes I and O where it intersects the perpendicular bisector of AC. So ABC is isosceles and we have:

$\angle BAC=\angle BCA=30^o$

$\Rightarrow \angle BCF=150^o$

$\Rightarrow \angle BCE=75^o$

$\Rightarrow \angle ECA=105^o$

$\Rightarrow \angle AEC=60^o$

$\angle BEA=\angle BAE=15^o$

$\Rightarrow \angle BEC=60+15=75^o$

$\Rightarrow \angle CBE=30^o$

that means:

$\angle CBO=\angle OBC+\angle CBE=60+30=9^o$

Also $BE=BC=BO$

$\Rightarrow \angle BEO=45^o$

which gives :

$\angle IEO=45-15=30^o$

Comment: sirous ... How do I guarantee that the bisector of the ABC triangle will go through $I$ and $O$? Did you make this restriction or does the problem statement allow you to do so?

Comment: @peta arantes , This is a special case.

Comment: @ACB..thanks...is what I was imagining...